# Struggling with custom SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, erd

I have to make a query to:

show a view which shows the results of counting all the employee dedications per employee area, listed by the area names in alphabetical order.

```
$this->db->query('create temporary table temp as (select dedication.employee_employeeID, dedication ID, COUNT(area) AS TotalFrequency from dedication, employees where dedication.employee_employeeID = dedication group by dedication.employee_employeeID)');
```

However, doesn't seem to be working on my website?

here is my relationships:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDdN5.png)

Comment: Please define “not working.”

Comment: `interest.staff_staffID = interest.interestID` is this correct? What is the `customers` table doing in this select? If it's a self join, that's fine. Just trying to understand what you want.

Comment: Error Number: 1066
Not unique table/alias: 'interest'
create temporary table temp as (select interest.staff_staffID, interestID, COUNT(industry) AS TotalFrequency from interest, interest where interest.staff_staffID = interest.interestID group by interest.staff_staffID)

Comment: You need to group by interestID as well, since it's in the SELECT.

Comment: i have added a diagram of tables: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDdN5.png

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend writing the query like this:

```
create temporary table temp as
    select c.industry, count(*) AS TotalFrequency
    from interest i JOIN
         customers c
         on i.staff_staffID = c.interestID
    group by c.industry;
```

This is just a guess.  You haven't provided table layouts.  The `join` conditions are quite strange (but wouldn't result in an error, just non-matches).